# How to import Data from CSV file to MySQL database without using LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax?

Tags: .net, mysql, csv

How to import Data from CSV  file to MySQL database without using LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax?

Comment: Is there a solid reason why not to use this method? its built for the job so I'm just interested as to why you want to use something else - not trolling, promise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most pedestrian way: open the .csv as text file, parse/split each line into a list of values, feed them to a prepared command "INSERT INTO table (field, ..) VALUES( ?, ...)"

Still with loop: use ADO/OleDb to open the .csv as table, feed each row's data to the statement.

Nice method (if doable): use ADO/OleDb to access the .csv and execute a "SELECT/INSERT INTO" statement specifying the MySQL database as external (ODBC).

A schema.ini file for the .csv is needed for the the last two approaches.